# How to export local geth data from a smart contract into Excel

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a local Geth network running with a smart contract that generates transactions containing several variables - as part of my data analysis I want to export the contents of the transactions to Excel. Is this possible?

I know Etherscan has an API but I don't know how to use that to parse through my local blockchain. I also looked at quickBlocks, but that seems to not have a Windows installation.

What I would like is to access the contract address and pull the data (transactions) pertaining to that contract. Anyone know how to go about this?